# How do I display cropped image on homepage in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, crop

How do I show cropped image of a very long image in wordpress and place a " Read More " permalink to the full article/post at the bottom . Like this

This is from the home page

http://s28.postimg.org/l8qbm85rh/image.jpg

This is the full post ( the original image is very long )

http://s28.postimg.org/85zagp4x9/image.jpg

Comment: You could just do a css `overflow:hidden` on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options for cropping an image. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/7RWe7/) jsfiddle includes a couple.
Uncomment the styles in the css section to view 2 ways of doing this.

*HTML*

```
<div>
    <img id="myImage" src="http://s28.postimg.org/85zagp4x9/image.jpg">
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
/*div{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}*/
```

OR

```
/*#myImage {
    position:absolute;
    clip:rect(150px, 650px, 640px, 140px);
}*/
```

Comment: Ok. The cropping works . But now how do I make this work for every image . Also how do I link this image to the whole post . And when user comes to the whole post will this cropped image be seen along with full image ?

Comment: For every image to be cropped like that, use img instead of #myImage. This will crop all images on your webpage to the same dimensions. What do you mean by whole post?

Comment: See . In my question the first image is cropped ( this is on homepage ) . And when someone clicks " view full post " he/she is redirected to the whole article . Will this cropped image ( your method ) display along with the full image in the article . In the second image ( in the question ) there is title and then the whole pic . No cropped image is displayed .

Comment: You can add this code to whichever pages you want to use the crop for. So if you want all your pages to include the image cropping, you can insert a link to the css that allows that. If you don't want the image to be cropped, you don't need to add the code to the webpage. Does that help?

Comment: Umm no . See these images 

This is the homepage with cropped image 

http://s12.postimg.org/o55yjfcq5/image.jpg

Now this is the whole article .

http://s12.postimg.org/yt9pi9mp9/image.jpg

You see , the cropped image and the original large image both appear in the whole article .

Comment: In your main page you're linking to a different image. The image I think you want is this one: http://s12.postimg.org/o55yjfcq5/image.jpg and you are using this one: http://s12.postimg.org/yt9pi9mp9/image.jpg

Comment: Sorry I don't understand . What I want to say is the cropped image should only be displayed in post excerpt , not in the full article .

Comment: Can you send me the link to your main webpage? I can only find links to the images you have in the comments.

Comment: I dont have a live website . Testing it on my computer locally .

Comment: Wait I will upload full screenshots .

Comment: Are you able to create a jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/) using your html code? (you only need to include the body in fiddle

Comment: This is my homepage with all the latest posts . See the cropped images .  http://s30.postimg.org/hm0dw8ou9/100.jpg . Now when I go to the real full article by clicking the title I get this http://s30.postimg.org/rusv22cw1/1001.jpg . Cropped image along with the full article . I just want to display cropped image on homepage .

Comment: I think it would be something " {display:none;} "

Comment: Ah ok makes much more sense! Thank you. The easiest way of doing this would be to have 2 sets of images. The first set of images would be what you see on your homepage. The second set of images would be what you want to be seen when you click on that image. If that is not an option or if you would rather use the same image for both, the only way of doing that would be to use css clip:rect() and clip out the bottom half of the image.

Comment: What I would actually suggest is that you use 2 sets of images (one for main page and one for when the image on the main page is clicked). Then use javascript or jquery to set all the images to the same width and proportionally change the height value of the images so they aren't skewed/stretched.

Comment: Is there any other position value can I use . Absolute misaligns the other . Displayed over other posts . And div screwed up the whole theme .

Comment: If you set each "post" as position:relative, You can then set the inner divs as absolute. The post information you can set to top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; and width:50%;. The post picture you can set to top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; and width:50%; For padding to these (if you want) add another div with class name say "padding" and add the css .padding{margin:10px;} - Or whatever padding you'd like. This will maintain the 50% width you set and add a fake padding.

Comment: So each individual post would have the format:
<div class="post">
    <div class="leftPane">
        <div class="padding">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="rightPane">
    <div class="leftPane">
        <div class="padding"><!--Padding optional-->
            IMAGE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

And your css:

.post{
    position:relative;
    /*Whatever other style you already have for each post*/
}
.leftPane{
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:50%;
}
.rightPane{
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:50%;
}

Comment: And: .padding{ margin:10px; } followed by your "CONTENT"'s css I will give a jsfiddle link in a minute

Comment: Sorry I don't know coding . I cant understand anything . The cropped image in sitting on top of other image like this http://s23.postimg.org/iy3c8g1pn/oooooo.jpg 

Can you show me the code to put it under its own title .

Comment: Here take a look http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/767Jt/ Replace content with title and image with the actual image

Comment: But where is the cropping/clipping in this code . It just displayed Title and the full sized image side bey side . :(

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/767Jt/1/ In the css section play with the rect values til you're happy with the crop, and set left and top as I have said in the comments above those lines of code

Comment: This is very complex x__x . Now how do I display this only on homepage and not in the full blog post/article . Not like this http://s30.postimg.org/rusv22cw1/1001.jpg

Comment: You told something about 2 images . But how do I hide the first cropped image ?

Comment: So add that code to the webpage you want to have that on. For the other webpage (I'm guessing the link) you want to give the image you want hidden a class (in html) so it would look something like this: <img src="yoururl" class="hideMe"> where yoururl is the actual image url and in the css for that page you would have: .hideMe{display:none;}

Comment: There is a problem . In your code img is screwing up all the other images of the website . All images are getting cropped . Anyway to distinguish it ?

Comment: Yes look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/767Jt/3/ I added ".crop>' in front of the img in css which basically says change only the img elements on the webpage that are a child of the crop class (which is the parent div's class name)

Comment: There are many other problems too . The code works in jsfiddle site and i also tried on some online html editors . The code works there but not on my blog . The code was misaligning almost everything . Titles of one post overlapping with other etc . So I changed "post" to " posta" , "leftpane" to "leftpanea" and rightpane to "rightpanea" . Now it doesnt mess with other articles but the code isnt working . Image is not being displayed at all . :( . Looks like wordpress uses same class/id like yours .

Comment: Hooray !!! It finally worked perfectly . Thank You so much . One last thing , I am looking to clip the image to 580x300 something . What would be the code for that . :D

Comment: It depends on where the top left corner is situated of the clipping area. If you are clipping from point 0, 0 (top left corner of image) you would use clip:rect(0, 580, 300, 0); if you're clipping from another point, say (10, 25) you'd write clip:rect(25, 590, 325, 10); where I added the starting points to the width and height respectively. rect(from top, width, height, from left) So you add "from top" to height(=300) and "from left" to width(=580)

Comment: Here I modified it so you can add a border to it: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/767Jt/5/ You can now edit the width and height properties in css directly (with less confusion than with clip) and position it with background-position where the first value is from the left and the second is from the top. Make sure you use the proper values (you will likely be using negative values like -200)

Comment: Can you help me with this too please . I am using this code for a dropdown menu http://jsfiddle.net/RQY5r/ . I changed the background colour to blue . Now see in this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/cNuT8.png the top portion on hover is still blue . I want to make it like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/1fxWT.png . Fully white on hover . :)

Comment: Also how do I hyperlink the clipped image ?

Comment: I think common practice on stack overflow is to ask another question if you need to ask another one, not to comment (i don't think I have the ability to change your comment to a question, however I will help you. Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/RQY5r/2/

Comment: I removed all the sections that added rounded borders to the elements and changed the line-height attributes to 35px from 21px. I also removed the margin-top on the li element to make the menu items vertically centered

Comment: Any idea on how to hyperlink the image like this http://s28.postimg.org/l8qbm85rh/image.jpg .. " View Full Post "

Comment: For hyperlinks envelop whichever element you want to be a link with <a href="hyperlink">The element you want to be a link or some text here</a>

Comment: But how do to I get that "view full post" link .I know what you told me about the borders . But for a normal image how do I do it ? I tried adding grey borders on 3 sides and a bigger border at border-bottom but how do I put the "view full post" link ?

Comment: For css borders, take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp for individual sides, scroll down the page to "Border - Individual sides"